# Como fazer uma ScrollBar personalizada?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Como modificar a scrollbar de uma `div`, para aparecer como no exemplo da imagem abaixo (Hangouts), em vez da scrollbar padrão do sistema operacional?

[image: barra de rolagem]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Existem literalmente dezenas de *plugins* de barras de rolagem, então a melhor solução é encontrar uma que esteja de acordo com suas necessidades ao invés de reinventar a roda, já que esta não é uma tarefa trivial.

Em uma [relação de *plugins*](http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/07/jquery-scrollbar-plugin-examples/), analisei alguns que pareciam mais promissores em 3 navegadores (Chrome, IE 7 e Firefox) e seleccionei dois:

### [Nano Scroller](http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/)

- *Clean*, compacto, rápido e funcional.
- Suportando rolagem com o rato.
- Se comportou bem nos 3 navegadores.

### [Nice Scroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/demo.html)

- Visual um pouco mais simples do que o Nano, mas também se comportou bem em todos os testes.
- A rolagem tem algum efeito para ficar mais suave, mas pessoalmente eu não gostei desse detalhe.
- Tem uma opção para maximizar o elemento em "tela cheia" (ajustar ao tamanho da página), mas não creio ser muito usual.

**Nota**: Ambos suportam dispositivos de toque (*touch*), porém não cheguei a incluir no teste por falta do *hardware*.

Comment: Um aspecto muito importante é o suporte para toque (_touch_), podes adicionar esse _feedback_ para completar a resposta.

Comment: @Zuul Bem lembrado! Obrigado.

Comment: @utluiz por que tu não testa no simulador do chrome?

Comment: @AndreyHartung O motivo é que não confiava em simuladores para dar a palavra final sobre isso. Não sei o quão confiáveis eles estão agora, mas pelo menos era assim na época que respondi à pergunta.

Answer (score 12):

Puro CSS. Mas só funciona em browsers Webkit, como Google Chrome, Safari e Opera. Use assim:

```css
/* Largura da barra de rolagem */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

/* Fundo da barra de rolagem */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background-color: #EEE;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCC
}

/* Cor do indicador de rolagem */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical,
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    background-color: #BAC0C4
}

/* Cor do indicador de rolagem - ao passar o mouse */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical:hover,
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal:hover {
    background-color: #717171
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N5jC6/

Veja outros estilos de barra de rolagem aqui: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-webkit-vertical-scrollbars/

Comment: Os browsers Chrome e Opera atualmente utilizam o Blink, e não o Webkit como era anteriormente, porém, o Blink por ser uma espécie de "fork" do projeto Webkit, ainda suporta a maioria das features para Webkit, o que incluí a solução desta resposta.

Comment: Interessante, algo que já existia a dez anos atrás no IE6 começa a ser padronizado pela w3c. Corrige sua resposta, IE também suporta veja http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531155(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: ótima resposta!

Answer (score 3):

Eu sugiro o pluigin [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) para o jQuery, ele oferece uma variedade de maneiras de se customizar a barra de rolagem, de forma consistente entre os diferentes *browsers*. Exemplo de uso:

```
$(suaDiv).jScrollPane();

$(suaDiv).jScrollPane({
    showArrows:true,           // Mostrar setas? (as que se clica para rolar em "steps")
    arrowScrollOnHover: true,  // Rolar ao passar o mouse sobre a seta?
    verticalGutter: 30         // Espaço extra antes e depois da barra
    verticalDragMinHeight: 20, // Tamanho do "retângulo" (o que se arrasta pra rolar)
    verticalDragMaxHeight: 20
    ...
});
```

Se preferir uma solução nativa (i.e. somente CSS, sem bibliotecas JavaScript externas), veja [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14150577/520779) no SO em inglês para uma lista de maneiras de se fazer isso no Internet Explorer ou no Webkit (Chrome, Safari). Infelizmente, no momento não há nada desse tipo suportado pelo Firefox.

Comment: É, parece não ser trivial fazer sem plugins. Ele é responsivo?

Comment: @CalebeOliveira Experimente os demos no site do plugin. Me parece bem eficiente, mas imagino que isso dependa um pouco do browser usado e/ou das capacidades do computador/dispositivo.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizo o plugin [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

Muito bom o plugin e de facil configuração no seu layout.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizo o [Nano Scroller](http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/), inclusive contribui para ele no repositório do projeto no Github, acho um plugin interessante caso precise de uma solução desse tipo.

Porém, caso possa trabalhar com "Progressive Enhancement" sugiro alterar a barra através do CSS, funcionalidade essa que só funciona em navegadores Webkit, como informado pelo @utluiz.

Answer (score 0):

Este código css funciona bem:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 10px; height: 10px; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:enabled { background-color: #FFF; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical { background-color: #FF0000; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal { background-color: #FF0000; }
```

Boa sorte!