# como mudar cursor e barra de rolagem direita do navegador

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Como mudar o cursor do mouse e a barra de rolagem direita pois fiz muitas pesquisas e todas cursor com o default padrão da tag 
exemplo do código:

```
.mouse{
cursor: pointer;
}
```

e não e assim queria um cursor  como nesse site por exemplo claro que não sera o mesmo =3:

http://memorial.grandchase.com.br/

e também a barra de rolagem que não faço ideia de como muda-lá.

Answer (score 1):

O cursor você pode pode mudar usando a propriedade `cursor` especificando uma imagem. Exemplo:

```
elemento {
    cursor:url(http://placehold.it/15x15);
}
```

É sempre bom você dar um segundo argumento, para que quando a imagem não seja carregada, o próximo cursor seja chamado:

```
elemento {
    cursor:url(http://placehold.it/15x15), default;
}
```

Demo no JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/awtLgkvp/

---

Sobre a barra de rolagem, **não** é recomendado mudá-la, uma vez que isso não consta nos padrões da W3C. O máximo que você pode conseguir é mudar a barra de rolagem em um ou dois navegadores, e mesmo assim utilizando bastantes linhas de CSS (o que acarretará em dados inúteis para os usuários que não usam esses navegadores).

Acho bacana uma solução usando JavaScript, mas a ideia em si não é boa. Pode ler mais sobre isso em outras perguntas semelhantes:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725652/css-scrollbar-style-cross-browser
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div/14150577#14150577

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor: url('seu_cursor_personalizado.cur'), apontar;
```

Quanto a barra de rolagem, dá uma olhada nesse tópico daqui do stackoverflow:
[Como fazer uma ScrollBar personalizada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1680/como-fazer-uma-scrollbar-personalizadc)

Comment: vou testar isso agora mesmo mais eu salvo com a extensão .cur ??

Comment: Não precisa ser um .cur não, pode ser outro tipo de imagem.
No fim da pagina desse link, tem uma tabela com o suporte dos navegadores:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor/url