# Mudar a Scrollbar através do CSS no Chrome

Tags: css

Coloquei border-radius na minha scrollbar, porém ficam sobras quando a cor de fundo é mudada, e gostaria de saber como retirar :

[image: barra]

Gostaria que ficasse nesse estilo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde não se vê mais a ::webkit-scrollbar-track

```css
body{
  height: 1280px;
  
}
div{
  width:100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 10px;
    
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #ffffff;
    
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 8px; 
    
}
```

```html
<div>Gostaria que a parte vermelha fosse todo o caminho da tela, atrás da barra verde</div>
```

Comment: Relacionada: [Como fazer uma ScrollBar personalizada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1680/3774)

Comment: Relacionada: [Personalização barra de rolagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90175/3774)

Comment: Cara coloca seu código ai, só com imagem não da para te responder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da uma olhada nesse aqui, é parecido com o que você quer. Usa um pouco de jquery para as funcionalidades de rolagem e touch para celulares mas recomendo que de uma olhada.

**Nanoscroller.js**

http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/

**Testado nos Navegadores/browsers de desktop:**

- IE7+
- Firefox 3+
- Chrome
- Safari 4+
- Opera 11.60+

**Mobile support:**

- iOS 5+ (iPhone, iPad and iPod Touch)
- iOS 4 (with a polyfill)
- Android Firefox
- Android 2.2/2.3 native browser (with a polyfill)
- Android Opera 11.6 (with a polyfill)

Para usar inclua no cabeçalho o arquivo javascript:

```
<script src="overthrow.js"></script>
```

... e adicione a classe em uma diva como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<div id="about" class="nano">
    <div class="overthrow nano-content"> ... content here ...  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder, geralmente todo mundo só reclama da pergunta. Vou dar uma olhada sim!

Comment: Tranquilo, boa sorte aí.